# Open/Closed set in Lebesgue measuer

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda(E)=0$ (the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$). Can $E$ be open? Must it be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1**: if $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a nonempty open set, it contains an interval of positive length.

**Hint 2**: Consider the rationals.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: open sets contain an interval of the form $(a,b)$. Another hint: find countable everywhere dense subset in $\Bbb R$.